# Problems while i'm trying to print a list

Tags: c, list

I am stuck in a problems with lists, the problem is that when i am trying to print the entire list it prints only the first node, the main goal is to have in tha main.c with only the call to the functions that are in the functions.c file that is conneted by the header.h file.
Here is the main.c file, nothing to say in particular here

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"



    int main(void){
    List l;


    listNotOrdered(&l, 6);
    headInsertion(&l, 10);
    printList(&l);
    }
```

That is the header.h file.

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
}Node;
typedef Node * List;

void listNotOrdered(List *l, int n);
void printList(List *l);
void headInsertion(List *l, int d);
```

That is functions.c, the logic behind all the funcitions it should be good, it doesn't give any errors, i've created a randomNumber functions, to create a list with random numebers, than to understan from what node the printList start to print, i added and headInsertion function, so when i print the list it only print the 10 value, so theoretically it only prints the first node.

```
void headInsertion(List *l, int dato){
    Node * aux = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    aux->data = dato;
    aux->next = *l;
    *l = aux;
}

void printList(List *l){
   while(l){
    printf("%d",(*l) -> data);
    (*l) = (*l) -> next;
   }
}

int randomNumber(int a){
    return a = -10 + rand () % ( 20 - 100 + 1);
}

void listNotOrdered(List *l, int n){
srand ( time ( NULL ));
int number, i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        (*l) = (Node*)malloc (sizeof (Node));
        (*l) -> data = randomNumber(number);
        (*l) -> next = NULL;
        l = &(*l)->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `l` to `NULL`, otherwise the list will never terminate.

Comment: Never ever `typedef` a pointer! This just not only error-prone, but also inhibits  or complicates good coding pracice like `const`-correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect it should print?

Because you are printing only once in `printList` and returning.

```
void printList(List *l){
    printf("%d",(*l) -> data);
    (*l) = (*l) -> next;
}
```

If you want to print all the nodes you have to traverse the list like below.

```
void printList(List *l){
 List temp = *l;
  while(temp)
  {
     printf("%d\n",temp -> data);
     temp = temp -> next;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Michelangelo Make sure you use `temp` variable, otherwise you end up changing the actual `head`